# Rails: method date_select how can I include :class for each select box in the dom?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want to each select box of my date_select have a different :class.

Like that:

```
<select id="user_birth_date_3i" name="user[birth_date(3i)]" class="class_1">
<select id="user_birth_date_2i" name="user[birth_date(2i)]" class="class_2">
<select id="user_birth_date_1i" name="user[birth_date(1i)]" class="class_3">
```

I try this in my view

```
= f.date_select :birth_date, {:start_year => Date.today.year - 5,  :end_year => Date.today.year - 65, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'Dia', :month => 'Mês', :year =>'Ano' } }, {:class => "birth_date"}
```

But now all of my select boxes are:

```
<select id="user_birth_date_3i" name="user[birth_date(3i)]" class="birth_date">
<select id="user_birth_date_2i" name="user[birth_date(2i)]" class="birth_date">
<select id="user_birth_date_1i" name="user[birth_date(1i)]" class="birth_date">
```

Comment: Could you please provide what you've already tried in Ruby On Rails?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the `date_select` helper method has an option that will allow you to specify different classes for the 3 select elements.  But, according to the documentation there is an option called `with_css_classes` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) that will add the different classes of `year`, `month`, and `day` to the select tags.  Perhaps you can use these in your css, jQuery selectors, or whatever it is that you might need different classes for.  Example:

```
<%= date_select("obj", "attribute", with_css_classes: true) %>
```

Produces:

```
<select id="obj_attribute_1i" name="obj[attribute(1i)]" class="year">...</select>
<select id="obj_attribute_2i" name="obj[attribute(2i)]" class="month">...</select>
<select id="obj_attribute_3i" name="obj[attribute(3i)]" class="day">...</select>
```